# query sql server in multiple database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, visual-studio, t-sql

i would like to execute this query 'select count(*) from Aircraft' on multiple database. We have 50 database and all of those have the same table. i'm using sql server 2019.
I know there is a possibilty to loop this query so that's why i'm asking you.

I found some old reply but not recently.

I used this query but it didn't work

```
SELECT @Query = COALESCE(@Query + ' UNION ALL ', '') + 'select * from [' + TABLE_CATALOG+'].dbo.[Aircraft]'
FROM information_schema.tables 

SET @Query = STUFF(@Query, CHARINDEX('UNION ALL', @Query), 10, '')

PRINT @Query

EXEC(@Query)
```

Comment: I don't see a `select count(*)`, I see a `select *`, and it requires that all the tables `Aircraft` have the same structure when you want to `union all` of them.

Comment: The error message returned would be helpful, in addition

Comment: "...but it didn't work" will not help resolving your issue.

Answer (score 2):

If all target databases are located in one instance, this can be done using the string_agg function in the following way:

```
Declare @schema_name sysname = N'dbo'
Declare @table_name sysname = N'Aircraft'
Declare @max nVarChar(max) = ''
Declare @QueryText nVarChar(max)

Select @QueryText = String_Agg(Concat(@max, N'Select * From ', 
                                            QuoteName([name]), N'.',
                                            QuoteName(@schema_name),N'.', 
                                            QuoteName(@table_name), Char(10)),
                               Concat(N'UNION ALL',Char(10)))
From master.dbo.sysdatabases 
Where OBJECT_ID(Concat(QuoteName([name]),'.',
                       QuoteName(@schema_name),'.',
                       QuoteName(@table_name))) Is Not Null

Print @QueryText

Exec sp_executesql @QueryText
```

Comment: it's work thanks a lot but i justa have this message : End time : 2021-12-07T09:01:48.1282883+01:00. Sorry i'm not an expert. I don't know how to use the function that i have create. can you help me?

Comment: @gladiator06m You are welcome. Unfortunately, this is an unclear message to me. It would be better if I could take a look at the result.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by taking advantage of the undocumented stored procedure in SQL Server i.e. `sp_MSforeachdb`

```sql
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(1000)

SET @query = 
'USE ?
IF DB_NAME() NOT IN (''master'', ''tempdb'', ''model'', ''msdb'')
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Count FROM ?.dbo.fin_MemberAccount'

EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @command1 = @query

-- ? : this means the current db while iterating through db by stored procedure
```